# Program Crashing while sorting array of structure pointers using qsort()

Tags: c, structure, qsort

Hi below is the program that I am trying to sort using `qsort()`. I am sorting it with respect to `int avg`. It prints junk values post sorting and crashes. I am certain there is something wrong in `compare()` but not sure what it is. Can someone please help.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#define LIMIT 3
int compare(const void *, const void *);

struct player
{
char name[10];
int age;
int n_o_t;
int avg;
};

int compare(const void *a,const void *b)
{
struct player *A=a;
struct player *B=b;
return(B->avg - A->avg);
}

int main()
{
struct player * game[LIMIT];
int i=0;

for(i=0;i<LIMIT;i++)
{
    game[i]=malloc(sizeof(struct player));
    if(game[i])
    {
        printf("Enter details\n");
        fflush(stdin);
        //fgets(game[i]->name,9,stdin);
        gets(game[i]->name);
        printf("age not ave\n");
        scanf("%d %d %d",&game[i]->age,&game[i]->n_o_t,&game[i]->avg);
        fflush(stdin);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("unable to allocate memory\n");
    }
}

for(i=0;i<LIMIT;i++)
{
    printf("%s %d %d %d \n",game[i]->name,game[i]->age,game[i]->n_o_t,game[i]->avg);
}

qsort(game,LIMIT,sizeof(struct player),compare);

printf("\nNow the sorted struct is\n\n");

for(i=0;i<LIMIT;i++)
{
    printf("%s %d %d %d \n",game[i]->name,game[i]->age,game[i]->n_o_t,game[i]->avg);
}

return 0;

}
```

I have made the required changes in the code below. Now it's running fine **yet not sorting the array.**

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#define LIMIT 5
int compare(const void *, const void *);

struct player
{
char name[10];
int age;
int n_o_t;
int avg;
};

int compare(const void *a,const void *b)
{
struct player *A=a;
struct player *B=b;
return(B->avg - A->avg);
}

int main()
{
struct player * game[LIMIT];
int i=0;

for(i=0;i<LIMIT;i++)
{
    game[i]=malloc(sizeof(struct player));
    if(game[i])
    {
        printf("Enter details\n");
        fflush(stdin);
        fgets(game[i]->name,9,stdin);
        game[i]->name[strlen(game[i]->name)-1]='\0'; // to remove trailing newline char
        printf("age n_o_t ave\n");
        scanf("%d %d %d",&game[i]->age,&game[i]->n_o_t,&game[i]->avg);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("unable to allocate memory\n");
    }
}

for(i=0;i<LIMIT;i++)
{
    printf("%s %d %d %d \n",game[i]->name,game[i]->age,game[i]->n_o_t,game[i]->avg);
}

qsort(game,LIMIT,sizeof(struct player *),compare);

printf("\nNow the sorted struct is\n\n");

for(i=0;i<LIMIT;i++)
{
    printf("%s %d %d %d \n",game[i]->name,game[i]->age,game[i]->n_o_t,game[i]->avg);
}

return 0;

}
```

If the input is

`n1 11 12 **15**
n2 16 18 **19**
n3 22 25 **0**
n4 77 66 **88**
n5 3 2 **1**`

The output would be

`n1 11 12 **15**
n2 16 18 **19**
n4 77 66 **88**
n3 22 25 **0**
n5 3 2 **1**`

The above matrix should have got sorted with respect to the last digit

Comment: `fflush(stdin);` = undefined behavior.

Comment: You have the `width` argument wrong in the call to `qsort`. `game[]` is an array of pointers, not structs.

Comment: ...so because the size of the struct is bigger than the size of a pointer, `qsort` is swapping stuff outside the bounds of the array `game[]`. And because `compare` isn't getting the pointers it is expecting, the result will be undefined.

Comment: It's far more likely that a problem such as you describe is with your swaps than that it is with your comparisons, and indeed, that's where the problem is.

Comment: As an aside, do note that implementing an integer comparison with the idiom `return b - a;` is flawed unless you are prepared to assume more constraints on the values of `b` and `a` than are implied by their types alone.  You may indeed be willing to do that here, but if in any case an `int` cannot hold the arithmetic value of `b - a` then you obtain undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since you have a list of pointers, qsort will give a pointer to the pointer. Also, your fscan probably needs some help

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define LIMIT 5
int compare(const void *, const void *);

struct player
{
  char name[10];
  int age;
  int n_o_t;
  int avg;
};

int compare(const void *a,const void *b)
{
  struct player *A=*(struct player **)a; /* note the double ** */
  struct player *B=*(struct player **)b; /* note the double ** */
  return(B->avg - A->avg);
}

int main()
{
  struct player * game[LIMIT];
  int i=0;

  for(i=0;i<LIMIT;i++)
  {
    game[i]=malloc(sizeof(struct player));
    if(game[i])
    {
      printf("Enter details\n");
      fflush(stdin);
      fgets(game[i]->name,9,stdin);
      game[i]->name[strlen(game[i]->name)-1]='\0'; // to remove trailing newline char
      printf("age n_o_t ave\n");
      scanf("%d %d %d",&game[i]->age,&game[i]->n_o_t,&game[i]->avg);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("unable to allocate memory\n");
    }
  }

  for(i=0;i<LIMIT;i++)
  {
    printf("%s %d %d %d \n",game[i]->name,game[i]->age,game[i]->n_o_t,game[i]->avg);
  }

  qsort(game,LIMIT,sizeof(struct player *),compare);

  printf("\nNow the sorted struct is\n\n");

  for(i=0;i<LIMIT;i++)
  {
    printf("%s %d %d %d \n",game[i]->name,game[i]->age,game[i]->n_o_t,game[i]->avg);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
struct player *A=*((struct player**)a);
struct player *B=*((struct player**)b);
```

Also, here:

```
game[i]=(struct player*)malloc(sizeof(struct player));
```

These are explicit pointer casting. Also, here:

```
qsort(game,LIMIT,sizeof(struct player*),compare);
```

Since the `game` array is composed of type `struct player*`.

Also, I would suggest using `getline()` in place of `gets()` and `fflush()`. Rest, I guess, is fine.

Comment: I have updated the code with mentioned corrections yet it's not sorting though not crashing anymore.

Comment: @ram619 sorry for that. I edited the comparator function and now it's working. The problem was that the parameters to the `compare` function are of type pointers to the array elements, so the type of `a` and `b` was `struct player**` and not `struct player*'. Also, I would recommend not using `fflush()` and `gets()`, since it isn't taking in the names of other players since the `\n' in the buffer is being passed as input to the next name.